# Send a DM to any user from one of the servers the BOT is in

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a feature in my bot where it sends the DMs it gets from users to the bot's official server along with user's ID. So I'd like to be able to respond to the messages with a command which would do the job for me.
Here's what I have so far:

```
def is_owner(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == my_id
@commands.check(is_owner)
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, id:discord.User, *text):
    message = " ".join(text)
    for member in client.guilds:
        user = client.get_user(id)
    await user.send(message)
    await ctx.author.send("Message sent!")
@dm.error
async def dm_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.CheckFailure):
        pass
```

When I run the code, I get this error and I can't seem to fix it:

```
Ignoring exception in command dm:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\servi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
  packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
  await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\servi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
  packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 851, in invoke
await self.prepare(ctx)
File "C:\Users\servi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
  packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 786, in prepare
await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
File "C:\Users\servi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
  packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
File "C:\Users\servi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
  packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 552, in transform
return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
File "C:\Users\servi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
  packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 505, in do_conversion
return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
File "C:\Users\servi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
  packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 451, in _actual_conversion
ret = await instance.convert(ctx, argument)
File "C:\Users\servi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
  packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 239, in convert
raise UserNotFound(argument)
discord.ext.commands.errors.UserNotFound: User "user_id_that_i_specified" not found.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the id is valid, have you checked with other ids?

Comment: I tried three accounts, none of them worked.

Comment: How did you use the command? `?dm @user`?

Comment: `.dm user_id message`
Anyways, someone responded with the code below and it works now. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `await client.fetch_user(id)` to get the user object.

```py
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, _id : int, *, text):
    user = await client.fetch_user(_id)
    await user.send(text)
```

You would run this like `!dm <specified_user_id> hello this is a test dm`

Comment: @Anonymous make sure to mark this answer correct if it worked for you!

Comment: I don't see why the converter fails, it is supposed to work

Comment: It doesn't matter, since OP is passing an id anyway.